# Multiple child table view controller in UIViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parent-child

I am a newbie Swift developer. I would like to receive some advice from experts on how to solve the following problem I am facing.

I am trying to embed in a UIViewController two child views controller and display both of them **at the same time** in the UIViewController, that is the parent view controller.

These two child view controllers are both UITableViewControllers: the first one is a table view with two sections and 3 rows per each section, the second child view is also a table but it displays some data dynamically.

Using the code below I managed to load and display each UITableViewController successfully but I can't display them both at the same time one below the other. 
Is there a way I can solve my problem?

Thank you so muck for your patience and kindness.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let firstTable = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstTable") as! UINavigationController
        let thirdTable = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdTable") as! UINavigationController

        self.addChildViewController(firstTable)
        firstTable.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(firstTable.view)
        firstTable.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.addChildViewController(thirdTable)
        thirdTable.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(thirdTable.view)
        thirdTable.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add container in the storyboard, this container can be connect to any view controller using control drag and selection embedded

[image]

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to show multiple UIViewControllers on the same UIViewController, Apple recommends using Container Views (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). 
In essence, they function as the child UIViewController's view target.
That way you can have multiple UIViewController views on a single UIViewController.

However, are you sure you need two separate controllers for your table views?
If you can get away with a single controller for two tableviews, I'd recommend using a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, add two UITableViews manually and add the required datasource and delegate methods to your UIViewController.